# Hide/Remove a perspective provided by another plugin - eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, perspective

I noticed that I had dependencies on some of the Eclipse JDT and Plugin development features and due to this the RCP was showing some other perspective from the other ui plugins, which is unnecessary entries in my product of Preference Perspective.

I tried with the below snippet, but still the perspective is showing in the preference perspective.

Call the removeUnWantedPerspectives() (attached below) method from postWindowCreate() method of your RCP’s WorkbenchWindowAdvisor extension class –

```
    private String[] IGNORE_PERSPECTIVES = new String[] {
       "com.abc.xyz.ui.calibrationPerspective" };

/**
 * Removes the unwanted perspectives from your RCP application
 */
private void removeUnWantedPerspectives() {
    IPerspectiveRegistry perspectiveRegistry = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPerspectiveRegistry();
    IPerspectiveDescriptor[] perspectiveDescriptors = perspectiveRegistry.getPerspectives();
    List ignoredPerspectives = Arrays.asList(GenericConstants.IGNORE_PERSPECTIVES);
    List removePerspectiveDesc = new ArrayList();

    // Add the perspective descriptors with the matching perspective ids to the list
    for (IPerspectiveDescriptor perspectiveDescriptor : perspectiveDescriptors) {
        if(ignoredPerspectives.contains(perspectiveDescriptor.getId())) {
            removePerspectiveDesc.add(perspectiveDescriptor);
        }
    }

    // If the list is non-empty then remove all such perspectives from the IExtensionChangeHandler
    if(perspectiveRegistry instanceof IExtensionChangeHandler &amp;&amp; !removePerspectiveDesc.isEmpty()) {
        IExtensionChangeHandler extChgHandler = (IExtensionChangeHandler) perspectiveRegistry;
        extChgHandler.removeExtension(null, removePerspectiveDesc.toArray());
    }
}
```

[image]
I tried with activities extension also, but this dosen't works for me

```
 <extension
      id="com.abc.xyz.pmse.application.activities.hideperspective"
      name="Hide Perspectives"
      point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
   <activityPatternBinding
         activityId="com.abc.xyz.pmse.application.activities.hideperspective"
         pattern=".*/com.abc.xyz.ui.calibrationperspective">
   </activityPatternBinding>
   <activityPatternBinding
         activityId="com.abc.xyz.pmse.application.activities.hideperspective"
         pattern=".*/com.abc.xyz.ui.varianthandlingperspective">
   </activityPatternBinding>
</extension>
```

My working activities extension snippet looks like

```
      <extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
     <activity
           id="com.abc.xyz.svn.ui.activity.hideunwantedperspective"
           name="Hide UnwantedPerspective">
        <enabledWhen>
           <equals
                 value="false">
           </equals>
        </enabledWhen>
     </activity>
   <activityPatternBinding
         activityId="com.abc.xyz.svn.ui.activity.hideunwantedperspective"
         isEqualityPattern="true"
         pattern="com.abc.xyz.ui.parameter.impl/com.abc.xyz.ui.calibrationperspective">
   </activityPatternBinding>
   <activityPatternBinding
         activityId="com.abc.xyz.svn.ui.activity.hideunwantedperspective"
         isEqualityPattern="true"
         pattern="com.abc.xyz.ui.dcmmapping/com.abc.xyz.ui.varianthandlingperspective">
   </activityPatternBinding>
   <activityPatternBinding
         activityId="com.abc.xyz.svn.ui.activity.hideunwantedperspective"
         isEqualityPattern="true"
         pattern="com.abc.xyz.ui.dcmmapping/com.abc.xyz.ui.varianthandlingperspectivenew">
   </activityPatternBinding>
</extension>
```

Comment: Use the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point to suppress UI elements you don't want.

Comment: Any example will be useful for hiding the perspective from other ui plugins

Comment: activities extension also doesn't work.

Comment: i tried with isEqualityPattern="false" &&   isEqualityPattern="true" also..

Comment: `activityId` must point to an `<activity>` entry not the extension point id (which isn't needed)

Comment: thanks greg-449 its working now